# Web Scraping with Python by Ryan Mitchell Chapter 3

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

I am trying to teach myself python web scraping. I came across this line of code that I cannot fully understand. The line I do not understand is.

```
for link in bs.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^(/|.*'+includeUrl+')')):
```

The larger code snippet is here.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime
import random

pages = set()
random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

#Retrieves a list of all Internal links found on a page
def getInternalLinks(bs, includeUrl):
    includeUrl = '{}://{}'.format(urlparse(includeUrl).scheme, urlparse(includeUrl).netloc)
    internalLinks = []
    #Finds all links that begin with a "/"
    for link in bs.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^(/|.*'+includeUrl+')')):
        if link.attrs['href'] is not None:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in internalLinks:
                if(link.attrs['href'].startswith('/')):
                    internalLinks.append(includeUrl+link.attrs['href'])
                else:
                    internalLinks.append(link.attrs['href'])
    return internalLinks
```

I understand that the includeUrl function already extracts the scheme and the netloc to create a full fledged link. As an example if we use the following url, we would get that result.

> 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' is the url,

> 'https' is the scheme

> stackoverflow.com netloc

So what exactly does this function do if you already have a well formed link like https://www.facebook.com? Does this only work for not complete links and can someone give me an example of how to correctly interpret this function?

Thank you.

Comment: includeUrl is not a function, it is a variable that contains a URL constructed three lines above.

Comment: The line that you don't understand contains only two function calls: `find_all()` and `compile()`. In the rest of the question you are talking about a variable (not a function) `includeUrl`. It is confusing and unclear which function and what exactly about it you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is an html parser. The `bs` object is the parsed DOM of the web you are scraping.

`for link in bs.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^(/|.*'+includeUrl+')')):`

Here, with `find_all` you get all the tags <a *> ... <\a>, and for each one of those tags, you only keep those that match the regular expression `'^(/|.*'+includeUrl+')'` by using re.compile()